# css menu hover "hangs" in chrome & safari

Tags: css, menu, webkit, hover

Greetings -
Struggeling with a three-level css menu.
Works fine in FireFox and Opera for mac, but in Chrome and Safari the third level "sticks" or "hangs" as a watermark after you move the cursor away.

I have tried a few different things without luck.

Live demo here:

http://www.it-stud.hiof.no/~benteh/tmp/

I have cut away everything else, so this is just the menu css & html.
(PS. there are only three levels on archeology, hominins and environmental)

Comment: That's a fine bug you found there. You definitely should report it: http://webkit.org/quality/reporting.html

Comment: I can confirm that it happens in Chrome, so it isn't just you.

Comment: I'd be happy to report it, but I cannot believe it is not fixable/work-around-able? It is probably easy, I have just stared at it for so long I cannot see the solution. And thanks both - glad to know it is not just me :-)

Comment: When a window is rerendered, e.g. after resizing or hovering over/selecting an element in the Web Inspector, the menu disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested to know that removing the "`visibilty: hidden`" rule from the "`.menu ul li ul`" selector (on line 105 of the CSS) fixes the problem for me in Chrome. Checked in FF3.6 and it works too - didn't check it in anything else.

Comment: Excellent. Like a lot of CSS though, don't ask me why ;)

Comment: Will give you cred for answer when my noob-status is upgraded :-)