# Superfish Drop Down Menu's IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, superfish

I am using drop down menu's on a website they work perfectly except for IE.

I have spent the last two hours trying to figure this out but i just cant seem to work out what the issue is.

I am using superfish for the menu's and once you mouse off the link the menu stays on screen for about 2-3 seconds and it's slightly out of position.

I tried css fixes on the ul but it only applied it to the jquery drop down not the instance that remains.

These images illustrate what is happening;

[image: Navigation working correctly]

[image: After image of the menu]

Here is the css / html for the menu;

## Markup

```
<div class="main-menu">
    <div class="menu-header">
        <ul id="menu-main" class="menu sf-js-enabled">
            <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40">
                <a class="sf-with-ul" href="http://wp.ashtonklein.com/ashton-klein/">
                Ashton Klein
                <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
                    <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49">
                        <a class="sf-with-ul" href="http://wp.ashtonklein.com/ashton-klein/about/">
                        About
                        <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
                            <li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-48">
                            <a href="http://wp.ashtonklein.com/ashton-klein/about/who-we-are/">Who we are</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47">
                            <a href="http://wp.ashtonklein.com/ashton-klein/about/our-vision/">Our Vision</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46">
                            <a href="http://wp.ashtonklein.com/ashton-klein/about/our-commitment/">Our Commitment</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45">
                        <a class="sf-with-ul" href="http://wp.ashtonklein.com/ashton-klein/opportunities/">
                        Opportunities
                        <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                            <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44">
                            <a href="http://wp.ashtonklein.com/ashton-klein/opportunities/careers/">Careers</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43">
                            <a href="http://wp.ashtonklein.com/ashton-klein/opportunities/franchising/">Franchising</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-42">
                            <a href="http://wp.ashtonklein.com/ashton-klein/opportunities/marketing-opportunities/">Marketing</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41">
                    <a href="http://wp.ashtonklein.com/ashton-klein/newsroom/">Newsroom</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul
{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;    
}
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li
{
    float:left;
    line-height:30px;
    font-family: 'Philosopher', arial, serif;
    font-size:18px;
    height:30px;
    margin:5px 15px 5px 0;
    padding:0 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20px;
    display:block;
}

#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li.current-menu-item, #header .webmenu .main-menu ul li.current-menu-parent, #header .webmenu .main-menu ul li.current-page-ancestor
{
    background:url('../images/menu_current.png') repeat-x;
}
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li a
{
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    outline:none;
}
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li:hover
{
    background:url('../images/menu_current.png') repeat-x;
}
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li span.sf-sub-indicator
{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:6px;
    height:4px;
    background:url('../images/menu_arrow.png') no-repeat right;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:13px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li ul.sub-menu
{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;

    /* corners */
    border-radius:0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 4px 4px;

    background:#007E63;
    padding:5px;
    height:auto;
    width:200px;
}
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li:hover ul.sub-menu
{
    display:inherit;
    left:0px;
    top:28px;
}
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li ul li
{
    display:block;
    float:none;
    background:none;
    margin-right:0;
    padding:0 10px;
    margin:0 0 3px;
}
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li ul li:hover
{
    background:#333333; 
}
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li ul li a, #header .webmenu .main-menu ul li ul li a:hover
{
    color:#FFF; 
}

#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li ul li.current-menu-item, #header .webmenu .main-menu ul li ul li.current-menu-parent
{
    background:#333333; 
}
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li ul li span.sf-sub-indicator
{
    background:url('../images/menu_arrow_sub.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:right;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    margin-top:8px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu
{
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;

    /* corners */
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;

    background:#007E63;
    padding:5px;
    height:auto;
    width:200px;
}
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li ul.sub-menu li:hover ul.sub-menu
{
    left:200px;
    top:0;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$('ul.menu').superfish({ 
        delay:       1000,                            // one second delay on mouseout 
        animation:   {opacity:'show',height:'show'},  // fade-in and slide-down animation 
        speed:       'slow',                          // faster animation speed 
        autoArrows:  true,                           // disable generation of arrow mark-up 
        dropShadows: false                            // disable drop shadows 
     });
```

I appreciate any help you can provide !

http://www.stylishmedia.co.uk/ak/

here is the link to a test version

Comment: @Xavier: Unrelated, but you should change `z-index: 20px;` to `z-index: 20;`

Comment: i did that change just to see if anything fixed itself but to my dismay still the same issue :)

Comment: @Xavier: Which version of IE are you using? or is it multiple versions?

Comment: I'll take a look at this if you provide either a link to a live page, or a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case where the issue happens.

Comment: it hangs in 8 and 7 (forget 6)

Comment: http://www.stylishmedia.co.uk/ak/ is the link to the test version

Comment: @Xavier: Just to let you know, you should prefix comments with @username if you want to notify a user. I didn't look back at your question after you added the live link and there was no notify, so I wasn't aware of it. Anyway, I'm glad you got this sorted.

Comment: @Thirtydot i am sorry i didn't realise the facility was available in the future i will use @username thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok this took a while to totally debug, the main thing with Superfish is that your menu should be working BEFORE adding the Superfish enhancements, yours wasn't, from their own documentation (with my bold):

> Superfish is an enhanced Suckerfish-style menu jQuery plugin that **takes an existing pure CSS drop-down menu** (so it degrades gracefully without JavaScript) and adds the following much-sought-after enhancements

#### Original Issue

The reason that you were getting the delay in effect is because you didn't apply the `li.sfHover` rules in the CSS to the same places that the `li:hover` was also used e.g.

```
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li:hover,
#header .webmenu .main-menu ul li.sfHover
{
    background:url('http://www.stylishmedia.co.uk/ak/wp-content/themes/AshtonKlein/library/images/menu_current.png') repeat-x;
}
```

do that in every place the `li:hover` is called and your original problem is fixed

#### Other things picked up along the way

I found it hard to debug this because IE wasn't working at all without the script, but once I got it working  e.g. IE7 and below didn't like the `float: right` of the indicator images, It was making the links which held them 100% wide which meant "Ashton Klein", the first link, was 100% of the top menu bar wide and was then throwing all the other menu items into the line below

the solution to this was to absolutely position the images, but this meant the links didn't get wide-enough to "margin" the images from the text, but Superfish also classes these links `sf-with-ul` so you can add extra right padding to them - and then position the images in the padded space

I changed quite a bit of the sizing of the menu links because it wasn't stable in IE at all, and varied across version as well as browser sometimes the drops were starting too high up the text, in FF they were actually cutting off.. you also can't use `display: inherit;` (well you should be able to but it's too buggy yet) which was why the menu wasn't reappearing without the script

sorry it's jumbled I think it's best to give the code so you can now take and compare your version with this one to see all the differences..

link to a [**working example**](http://jsbin.com/ulesi3)

if you comment out the script at the bottom you will see that it does now work without it too though no fancy delays going on obviously ;)

Comment: Clairesuzy all i have to say is THANK YOU ! Wow you worked it out to a T, @ the other issues thanks for sorting those too but that was a dummy example i had uploaded just for this purpose so i had fixed all the previous issues but nether-less i very grateful for your help !

<3

Comment: You're Welcome, good luck!.. I'd never really worked with Superfish before so it gave me a chance to check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have IE, but I had a veeery similar problem a while ago. I have not combed your stylesheet, but have a look at what solved it for me:
[css menu hover "hangs" in chrome & safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664383/css-menu-hover-hangs-in-chrome-safari)

Hope it helps.

Comment: ..so what I mean, is that you have some of those selectors inline, though.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't really help i know about inline display issues in IE.