# Why is a hover menu 'ghosting' in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, hover

When I hover over a menu in Chrome (Version 21.0.1180.79) only (not all webkit) and then unhover a portion of the menu is ghosting (staying in place) until an element is adjusted in it's place in which case the overlapped area goes away.

For example, on the page: http://www.georgianc.on.ca/student-success/ if you hover over 'Co-op and Career' (in chrome) and then unhover you should see the issue.

This question appears to be the same issue (I can't tell for sure as the example was taken down) but I can't find any 'visibility' rules that apply to the menu in question... need fresh eyes? [css menu hover "hangs" in chrome & safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664383/css-menu-hover-hangs-in-chrome-safari)

Screenshots:

after unhovering
[image: after unhovering]

after unhovering and then the slide changing
[image: after unhovering and then the slide changing]

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) a bit of code would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce on Chrome 21.

Comment: @Pekka makes sense. thanks. I'll try to reproduce in jsfiddle

Comment: can reproduce it on chrome 22/windows...

Comment: actually, I think the problem is fixed if you set `position:static` on `#menu-item-197`. don't know why though

Comment: @gengkev YES! that does seem to fix it in the inspector - we have a 24 hour cache on the live site, I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @gengkev bypassed the cache. that change worked. You should list it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the problem appears to be fixed if you set `position: static` on `#menu-item-197`. I don't know why, though, and it probably shouldn't ghost in the first place - but at least it works!

Answer (score 1):

can't reproduce on windows x64 gc v 21.0.1180.79 m

check if you have any plugins that may interfere with the website, like JQuery Injector, KB SSL Enforcer...

For example I am using KB SSL Enforcer and I could not see your website because of it.